# Quartz scheduler -HELP NEEDED

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have the following requirement.

I have to start 3-4 schedulers between a start an end date and the timings for these schedulers are 9am, 1pm, 5pm, 10pm. And these start and end dates vary. For eg: I have to start 3 schedulers between 5th-10th Jan and another might be say 13th-17th Jan. So these dates might vary. But the timings on these dates are fixed as mentioned above. But only thing is I might have to schedule job at 9am and 1pm on day, and only at 10pm on another day and so on. So the number of times vary.

Can anyone please suggest which job and triggers I can use. Is it possible to have one scheduler for this?

Comment: *"URGENT HELP NEEDED"*  1) Don't SHOUT at us! 2) For urgent help, urgently seek a consultant (and pay them a rate to match your urgency).

Comment: @Preethi: if the answer provided has solved your problem, better accept the answer so that other will come to know about the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough for you to start:

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.impl.triggers.AbstractTrigger;

import java.util.Calendar;

import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.dateOf;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

//...

AbstractTrigger trigger = (AbstractTrigger) newTrigger()
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 9,13,17,22 * * ?"))
        .build();
trigger.setStartTime(dateOf(0, 0, 0, 13, Calendar.JANUARY, 2012));
trigger.setEndTime(dateOf(0, 0, 0, 17, Calendar.JANUARY, 2012));

final JobDetail job = newJob(Job.class).build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

For more consult official [Lesson 6: CronTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) in the documentation.

Comment: And sorry if I didn't adhere to any rule.

Comment: Can I change this to have only some timings for the scheduler?        For eg: for one job I have to schedule for 9am and 10pm and another job I have to schedule for 9am,1pm and 10pm, likewise I have to schedule many jobs and for all this the start and end date will vary.

Comment: @Preethi: Look closely: `0 0 9,13,17,22 * * ?` - these numbers aren't random :-). Hint: [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Yes... thanks for the response. So is it possible to assign these to a variable and change dynamically  Something like int a=0 if(time is 9am){ a=9; AbstractTrigger trigger = (AbstractTrigger) newTrigger()
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 a,0,10,20 * * ?")) if(time is 10pm){ a=22 AbstractTrigger trigger = (AbstractTrigger) newTrigger()
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 0,0,0,a * * ?"))   something like this?